# php preg_match regex for multiple directories and files

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to write a regex expression in PHP that will load content in all locations specified, or every location except those specified.

```
#load content everywhere EXCEPT locations expressed
<?php if (preg_match('/\/(contact\/|news\/|index\.html)/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) === 0): ?>
<div class="greeting">Bonjour</div>
<?php endif; ?>

#load content on locations expressed
<?php if (preg_match('/\/(contact\/|news\/|index\.html)/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) === 1): ?>
<div class="greeting">Konichiwa</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The problem I'm having is that I can't get the root of my website `/index.html`(specifically http://example.com/index.html, nowhere else) to work alongside the wildcards for any page in `/contact/` or `/news/`.

To summarize again:
`/contact/*` (any page in contact), `/news/*` (any page in /news/), `/index.html` (root of website)

I've tried a few different ways of adding the slash before index.html, but it either didn't work or returned a PHP error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you use anchor `^` (line start) make sure you match URI from root:

```
if (preg_match('#^/(contact/|news/|index\.html|$)#', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))
```

I also changed regex delimiter to `#` so that you can avoid escaping `/` in your regex.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I tried it, but it still doesn't seem to be recognizing that index.html is the root like `example.com/` or `example.com`. As it did before, it still works for `/contact/*` and `/news/*`, but no matter what I do, it doesn't seem to recognize the root of the website.

Comment: What was the URL in your browser when you tested it?

Comment: I tried `example.com`, `example.com/`. It works with `example.com/index.html`, but I thought in this case it understood it on the server side since index.html was being loaded at the root when you just went to `example.com`. What can I do to define the front page of the domain in the regex instead of `index.html`?

Comment: Ok I made an edit to take care of just `example.com` in the URL. Pls check.